# C# winform parsing serial port data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

I am a newb armed with copy paste trying to get data from an old Avery-Weightronix 7820 weigh scale. I have it hooked up via an RJ-232 cable and have managed to get responses from the scale. I followed this tutorial https://www.studentcompanion.co.za/creating-a-serial-port-interface-with-c/ to get up and running.

Once I got it working I wanted to simplify it and essentially use my computer as a remote display. I hard coded the serial connection parameters and set up the code to send a request for the weight every second so I could display it in a winform.

Later I plan to extend it so I can get the total weight for multiple items. I plan to weigh an item, copy the weight to a running total, put a new item on the scale and repeat.

I am stuck at the moment because I am having trouble consistently parsing the data returned from the scale and because the loop locks up the UI.

When I send W`<CR>` which is the request for the current weight, an example response is:

`<LF>`0001.10lb`<CR>` `<LF>`00`<CR><ETX>`

Where `<ETX>` = End of text character (Ø3 hex), `<LF>` = Line feed character (ØA hex), `<CR>` = Carriage return character (ØD hex).

The response from the scale is fixed length but when I go into debug mode the response is not received during the first couple of cycles through the code. Then it arrives later. This is ok when I am outputting it to a rich text field but when I try to pull out a substring I get an error if there is no data.

Also, the UI locks and the only thing I can do it stop the execution. From reading around it seems I should implement threading but I am unsure how to reorganize my code to do this.

I would appreciate any pointers or advice on how to solve these issues.

This is the code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace ScaleView
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void groupBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //updatePorts();           //Call this function everytime the page load 
                                 //to update port names
        CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
    }
    

    private SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort();  //Initialise ComPort Variable as SerialPort
    private void connect()
    {
        bool error = false;

            
        ComPort.PortName = "COM3";
        ComPort.BaudRate = int.Parse("9600");      //convert Text to Integer
        ComPort.Parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), "Even"); //convert Text to Parity
            ComPort.DataBits = int.Parse("7");        //convert Text to Integer
            ComPort.StopBits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), "1");  //convert Text to stop bits

            try  //always try to use this try and catch method to open your port. 
                 //if there is an error your program will not display a message instead of freezing.
            {
                //Open Port
                ComPort.Open();
                ComPort.DataReceived += SerialPortDataReceived;  //Check for received data. When there is data in the receive buffer,
                                                                 //it will raise this event, we need to subscribe to it to know when there is data
                                                                 //MessageBox.Show(this, "Connected", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) { error = true; }
            catch (System.IO.IOException) { error = true; }
            catch (ArgumentException) { error = true; }

            if (error) MessageBox.Show(this, "Could not open the COM port. Most likely it is already in use, has been removed, or is unavailable.", "COM Port unavailable", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

        
       
        //if the port is open, Change the Connect button to disconnect, enable the send button.
        //and disable the groupBox to prevent changing configuration of an open port.
        if (ComPort.IsOpen)
        {
            btnConnect.Text = "Disconnect";
        }
    }
    // Call this function to close the port.
    private void disconnect()
    {
        ComPort.Close();
        btnConnect.Text = "Connect";
        
    }
    //whenever the connect button is clicked, it will check if the port is already open, call the disconnect function.
    // if the port is closed, call the connect function.
    private void btnConnect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {
        if (ComPort.IsOpen)
        {
            disconnect();
        }
        else
        {
            connect();
            rtxtDataArea.AppendText("Connected\n");
            sendData();
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear the screen
        rtxtDataArea.Clear();
    }
    // Function to send data to the serial port
    private void sendData()
    {
        bool error = false;
        while(ComPort.IsOpen)        //if text mode is selected, send data as tex
        {
            
            try
            {
                // Convert string of hex digits (in this case representing W<CR>) to a byte array
                string hextext = "57 0D";
                byte[] data = HexStringToByteArray(hextext);

                // Send the binary data out the port
                ComPort.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

                rtxtDataArea.ForeColor = Color.Blue;   //write Hex data in Blue
                string response = ComPort.ReadLine();
                int charfrom = 1;
                int charto = 9;
                //string weight = response.Substring(charfrom, charto - charfrom);
                rtxtDataArea.AppendText(response + "TEST\n");
                
            }
            catch (FormatException) { error = true; }

            // Inform the user if the hex string was not properly formatted
            catch (ArgumentException) { error = true; }

            if (error) MessageBox.Show(this, "Not properly formatted hex string: \n" + "example: E1 FF 1B", "Format Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop);

        }
    }
    //Convert a string of hex digits (example: E1 FF 1B) to a byte array. 
    //The string containing the hex digits (with or without spaces)
    //Returns an array of bytes. </returns>
    private byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string s)
    {
        s = s.Replace(" ", "");
        byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
            buffer[i / 2] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return buffer;
    }

    private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        sendData();
    }
    //This event will be raised when the form is closing.
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ComPort.IsOpen) ComPort.Close();  //close the port if open when exiting the application.
    }
    //Data recived from the serial port is coming from another thread context than the UI thread.
    //Instead of reading the content directly in the SerialPortDataReceived, we need to use a delegate.
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        //invokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the calling thread to the thread of the creating thread.
        // if these threads are different, it returns true
        if (this.rtxtDataArea.InvokeRequired)
        {
            rtxtDataArea.ForeColor = Color.Green;    //write text data in Green colour

            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        }
        else
        {
            this.rtxtDataArea.AppendText(text);
        }
    }
    private void SerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var serialPort = (SerialPort)sender;
        var data = serialPort.ReadExisting();
        SetText(data);
    }

    private void rtxtDataArea_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Use a separate `Thread` to handle the serial port connection and data transfer, and use `form.BeginInvoke(...);`  when the UI needs to refresh the data. Calling `BeginInvoke(...)` is expensive, so don't do it too often, at most once every 100 milliseconds.

Comment: Why would you want a separate thread for the connection and data transfer? If the connection is failing then you do not want to transfer data.  Two separate thread then means you have to be able to handle the connection occurring before the transfer.  You do need to be able to handle cross threading between the form thread and the serial port thread and using INVOKE will solve that issue.

Comment: No, I am well out of my depth on this so I was asking. Your point seemed to address the issue with getting the response information and Loathing's seemed to address the problem I was having with the UI becoming unresponsive. The code currently sends the response to a text field and continuously messages the scale for updates. The UI stops responding and I just have to close it out. If I fix the response parsing, will that take care of the UI issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `try-catch` blocks, and `MessageBox.Show(...)` in both the `connect()` and `sendData()` methods. The `try-catch` in the `new Thread(() => {` block will catch any exceptions and send them to the UI thread.

Delete the line `CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;` because it bypasses the built-in protection. The `serialPort.ReadLine();` method might be better than `serialPort.ReadExisting();` as `ReadLine()` will wait for a full line of data.

This should give you an idea of how the code might look:

```
Thread dataThread = null;
private void btnConnect_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (ComPort.IsOpen) {
        disconnect();
    }
    else {
        btnConnect.Enabled = false; // user has to wait for connection to succeed or fail. Prevents clicking the button twice.
        Form form = this;

        dataThread = new Thread(() => {
            try {
                connect();

                // if you get here then connect succeeded
                form.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
                    btnConnect.Enabled = true; // now becomes the Disconnect button
                    rtxtDataArea.AppendText("Connected\n");
                });

                // start sending and receiving data on the thread
                sendData();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                form.BeginInvoke((Action) delegate {
                    btnConnect.Enabled = true; // remains as the Connect button, user can try again
                    MessageBox.Show(form, ex.GetType().Name + ": " + ex.Message, "COM Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                });
            }
        });
        dataThread.IsBackground = true;
        dataThread.Start();
    }
}

delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
private SetTextCallback callSetText = new SetTextCallback(SetText); // don't create new delegates each time
    private void SetText(string text) {
    if (this.rtxtDataArea.InvokeRequired) {
        rtxtDataArea.ForeColor = Color.Green;    //write text data in Green colour
        this.BeginInvoke(d, new object[] { text }); // use BeginInvoke instead
    }
    else {
        this.rtxtDataArea.AppendText(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Finally got a chance this weekend to look at this. Thanks for this.